# dbpedia server status

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata

As [suggested](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Support) I'm wondering why wikidata sparql endpoint does not work: http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/sparql

General info: http://wiki.dbpedia.org/news/dbpedia-based-rdf-dumps-wikidata

Is it temporally as http error code suggests or is it simply not working anymore?

Comment: I believe it's temporary, and suggest you ping [@DBpedia](https://twitter.com/DBpedia) and/or [dbpedia-discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-discussion/) for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at this instead https://query.wikidata.org/ ?

Comment: Thanks, but that's a web interface. They seem to have rest sparql endpoint for programmatic access, but I was wondering why my code wasn't working when I realized that endpoint is down for quite some time